# Does Hybris 6 uses hibernate or has used in any past versions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

I don't have source code for `hybris 6` and wondering if `hybris` is using `hibernate` for its persistence layer.

Earlier until version 4 hybris provided source code and you can find whats going on underneath DAO calls but not anymore.

I have primarily worked on 4.8 and 5.4 versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hybris using own ORM. You can use auto decompile tools while debugging. You can enable logging for package de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch. There is problem in >6.0 hac logging screen, you can't find this package there, please follow below article for enabling it.
https://experts.hybris.com/questions/58660/hac-logging-configuration-in-60-and-above.html

Also you can enable JDBC logging in hac. Goto Monitoring > Database > JDB Logging for enabling it. More details are here https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/8c072d3c86691014b47a9dfeaec0fe3f.html